# Why multiple ip-port pair are negotiated for rtp when signaling is done by SIP

Tags: sip, rtp

Why multiple ip-port pair are negotiated for RTP when signaling is done by SIP. What is the maximum value of the number of ip-port negotiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each media line in an SDP description describes one RTP stream for one media in an SDP description: For each media (audio, video, desktop-sharing, ...) you will need 2 connections: one for RTP (ip:port from c= line) and one for RTCP (ip:port+1). There is no maximum on the number of media lines.

Additionnaly, the SDP can contains ICE ([rfc5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245)) candidates, which may also provide alternative LOCAL ip:port and alternative DESTINATION ip:port to exchange media. For example:

```
a=candidate:4273728266 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.125 43897 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:4273728266 2 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.125 43897 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:779251937 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.107 55273 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:779251937 2 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.107 55273 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2956466170 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.125 0 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2956466170 2 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.125 0 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1626442769 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.107 0 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:1626442769 2 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.107 0 typ host generation 0
```

In more recent rfc, you can find SDP extension to minimize the number of connections. The a=rtcp-mux (defined in [rfc5761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5761)) allow you to multiplex RTP and RTCP data on a single port. Then, instead of 2 ports per media, you just need one.

A second extension, only published as a draft (draft-ietf-mmusic-sdp-bundle-negotiation), can be used with the SDP Offer/Answer mechanism to negotiate the usage of a single address:port combination (BUNDLE address) for receiving media, referred to as bundled media, associated with multiple SDP media descriptions ("m=" lines).

With both those 2 last extensions, you can end-up with just one ip:port connection for all media lines and all RTP/RTCP streams of your SDP description.

Comment: Why are the alternate ip port pairs are sent? And after connection is set up on an ip:port pair, what happens with alternate pairs ? Will they be released for other connections or kept? will they be used after creation of connection

Comment: Alternative connections are provided to let the application search for the *best* connection (ie, a p2p connection). Note that, in practice, all UDP connections usually share the same "local port", so there is nothing to release as the same socket is used. For TCP alternative, I think (to be verified) they should be kept because if the selected connection is not working any more in the future, the others may still be good alternatives.

Comment: What if the ports are different? In case of my observation the ports were different in case of UDP. "Alternative ports can be of use to search of best connection". Can you please explain what exactly is the best connection, as all ports can be used. 

Is there any upper limit of the number of alternate ports shared ?

Comment: You can check ICE/rfc5245 spec [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245). Usually, you will have several UDP candidates using the same local port:  One for your local network interface, another one discovered with [STUN](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389) and a last one discovered with [TURN](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5766). In practice, an additionnal one with TURN over TCP is nice to have and you may have other ones if you have several local network interface. Thus, usually, you end up with 4 RTP candidates and 4 RTP candidates, but as far as I know, there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of ip:port pairs is up to client's SDP. If the posts multiple m-lines in SDP, client needs to allocated ip:ports for each m-line entry.